# How many indices are allowed for a Matlab matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I'm learning Matlab (actually, Octave) and something is really confusing me:

```
octave:14> a = [2 3 4]
                          a =

                             2   3   4

octave:15> a(1)
                          ans =  2
octave:16> a(1,1)
                          ans =  2
octave:17> a(1,1,1)
                          ans =  2
octave:18> a(1,1,2)
    error: A(I,J,...): index to dimension 3 out of bounds; value 2 out of bound 1

octave:18> a(2,1,1)
    error: A(I,J,...): index to dimension 1 out of bounds; value 2 out of bound 1
```

I expected `a(1, 1, 1)` to be illegal, but that's confusing me... how many indices are allowed for a matrix?

What does it *mean* when I say `a(1, 1, 1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an array, the first row, column, page, etc are always defined, as long as the array isn't empty.

So if

```
a = 3;

a(1) %# works
a(1,1) %# works
a(1,1,1) %# works
a(1,1,1,1) %# works
```

because the size of `a` is, theoretically, `[1,1,1,1,1,1,....]`

For convenience, the size of a scalar is given as `[1,1]`, i.e. the other dimensions of length 1 are not mentioned.